# how to solve for the eigenvectors of a tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a tridiagonal matrix

$A = \left[\begin{array}{cccc} 
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 & 2 \end{array}\right]$

where $A$ is an $4 \times 4$ matrix, size $n$, and rows are denoted as $j$

and the eigenvectors of $A$ is given by $v_s = [\sin(\frac{\pi }{n+1}), \dots, \sin(\frac{\pi \cdot n \cdot s}{n+1})]$ for every $n = 1:4$ and  $s = 1, \dots, n$.

when I input  $sin (i    1    \pi / 5)$ for every $i = 1:4$ to find the first eigenvector $ v_j(i)$     $j=1$, and iterate from 1 to 4.  The output doesn't correspond to the expected eigenvectors

$$A = \left[\begin{array}{cccc} 
1  \\ 
(\sqrt{5}+1) / 2  \\ 
(\sqrt{5}+1) / 2  \\ 
1 \end{array}\right]$$

The output I am getting in decimal form is 
$$A = \left[\begin{array}{cccc} 
0.58  \\ 
0.95  \\ 
0.95  \\ 
0.58 \end{array}\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the following scalar products: $v_1 v_2, v_1 v_3, v_2 v_3, v_2 v_4, ...$. In General, $v_s v_t = 0$ for $s \neq t$ and $s,t = 1:4$ must hold for orthogonality.

Moreover you must calculate $v_s v_s$; this must yield the value 1.

Comment: do the evectors using the following formula, hold true?    $v_s = [\sin(\frac{\pi s}{n+1}), \dots, \sin(\frac{\pi \cdot n \cdot s}{n+1})]$

Comment: yes, you can use this vector and then you can compute scalar products.